# What if I have a question that should be on both Stack Overflow and health site of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

If I am a programmer and I am creating web applications for medical purposes, can I ask a question on Stack Overflow for developers help and share it on health stack site as well to receive medical advice on how some things works to understand it while programming?

Or are two posts needed on both sites to get the needed help according to each part?

Comment: Here is the key.  MAKE SURE YOU CROSS-LINK THEM!  I once posted the same question on one SE then also on EE SE.  There were some comments saying it would have made their job easier if they had been able to see the answers being generated by the other guys.  All you have to do is add a line at the end of the Q that says:  This is also posted at (link to the other post)

Answer (score 5):

Do you really want programmers giving you advice on medical issues? Likewise do you need medical expertise to help you code your app?

You not only need different questions, but more than likely *vastly* different questions. Stack Overflow and Health have such a different scope that I doubt there are questions that would be acceptable on both.

Scope your questions to the site you are asking on. Read through the help on each site and research existing questions to see what is on-topic and how to ask a good focused question.

Comment: I posted a question on health about cvd calculations and it contains equation that need to be coded. I write the exact proper script and no one result. I posted the question on health, because it is not a programming issue. And so by that, I posted this question here.

Comment: @droidnation sure... but still you should ask the appropriate questions for the site. e.g. your question on Health likely wouldn't involve any code at all; just the relevant health/medical information. And your question on Stack Overflow would be about implementing your calculations in code only; not about the medical importance of the information

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you should care is ensure that the 2 questions are clearly on topic in the sites.

When asking in Stack Overflow, you should add the purpose but the medical related things will not help on Stack Overflow.

Similarly when asking on Health, add the purpose that you are developing an application. Codes won't help there.

Also link to the other post from each post.

Comment: So there is not an intermediate link between 2 sites on stack exchange. Each post should be on the related site with the only related information. Thanks

Comment: yes. A link to one from the other will help you if any one with previous experience in the same thing saw the post